# AP and WiFi client at same time

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless-adapter

I've an R-Pi and an Edimax USB WiFi adapter. I can connect to a network with the adapter, but I also want to make an AP on it.
I want it to act like a repeater (connect to network A, create network B and route all traffic trough network A).

Backstory:
I want a portable R-Pi. I want to create an AP so I can connect to the R-Pi network with my phone and login via SSH. I also want the R-Pi to have internet access.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: Dont remember so. I do know almost none of the USB adapters can connect to a wifi network and act like an access point at the same time. So you would neet at least 2 adapters. Also, not all adapters support creating access points. The built in network adapter in the Raspberry Pi supports creating an access point, you could use another USB adapter as WiFi source.